# Register abstract managed classes with generic managing class and preserve one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, generics

I have a couple abstract classes, and would like to make sure that the "Manager" is always registered with the "Managed" class such that they retain a two-way knowledge of the one-to-many relationship. That is, the Manager knows all of the Managed classes it has, and the Managed class knows who its Manager is (if it is registered with one). Further, I'd like the managed class to be able to call the specialization of its concrete manager without having to do a special cast. Is that possible?

I'd like something like this, but run into compilation issues:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConcreteManager manager = new ConcreteManager();
            ConcreteManaged managed = new ConcreteManaged() { Name = "Test" };

            manager.Add(managed);
            managed.Process();
        }
    }

    public abstract class BaseManager<ManagedType>
        where ManagedType : BaseManaged
    {
        protected Dictionary<string, ManagedType> registered = new Dictionary<string, ManagedType>();

        public void Add(ManagedType managed)
        {
            managed.Manager = this; // Cannot implicitly convert type 'BaseManager<ManagedType>' to 'BaseManager<BaseManaged>' (I've tried casting to no avail)
            registered.Add(managed.Name, managed);
        }
        // Other common management tasks
    }

    public class ConcreteManager : BaseManager<BaseManaged>
    {
        //specialization stuff, e.g.
        public void Refresh() { Console.WriteLine("Refresh Called"); }
    }

    public abstract class BaseManaged
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public BaseManager<BaseManaged> Manager { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConcreteManaged : BaseManaged
    {
        //specialization stuff, e.g.
        public void Process()
        {
            Manager.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

If I change the non `Program` classes around a bit, as follows, I can get it to compile, but there are runtime errors (Unable to cast object of type 'TestAbstractGenerics.ConcreteManager' to type 'TestAbstractGenerics.IBaseManager`1[TestAbstractGenerics.IBaseManaged]'.):

```
public interface IBaseManager<ManagedType>
    where ManagedType : IBaseManaged
{
    void Add(ManagedType service);
}

public abstract class BaseManager<ManagedType> : IBaseManager<ManagedType>
    where ManagedType : IBaseManaged
{
    protected Dictionary<string, ManagedType> registered = new Dictionary<string, ManagedType>();

    public void Add(ManagedType managed)
    {
        managed.Manager = (IBaseManager<IBaseManaged>)this;
        registered.Add(managed.Name, managed);
    }
    // Other common management tasks
}

public class ConcreteManager : BaseManager<BaseManaged>
{
    //specialization stuff, e.g.
    public void Refresh() { Console.WriteLine("Refresh() called"); }
}

public interface IBaseManaged
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    IBaseManager<IBaseManaged> Manager { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseManaged : IBaseManaged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IBaseManager<IBaseManaged> Manager { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteManaged : BaseManaged
{
    //specialization stuff, e.g.
    public void Process()
    {
        ((ConcreteManager)Manager).Refresh();
    }
}
```

If I change the `IBaseManager<IBaseManaged>` to `dynamic` I can remove the cast from `Process()` and everything works as expected, but dynamic doesn't work with intellisense, and I would like to be able to enforce the type checking (so an implementer can't accidentally set `Manager` to a `string`, for example). So what's the best practice here? Is there a good pattern to follow that allows me to preserve the one-to-many relationship?

And yes, in the above I'd have to add some logic to make sure that when `BaseManaged.Manager` is `set` that it unregisters from its current `Manager`, if any. I avoided that here for sake of simplicity.

Edit: this works, but still requires casting to the `ConcreteManager` prior to calling its non-interface methods:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var manager = new ConcreteManager();
        var managed = new ConcreteManaged() { Name = "Test"};

        manager.Add(managed);
        managed.Process();

    }
}

public interface IBaseManager<ManagedType>
    where ManagedType : IBaseManaged
{
    void Add(ManagedType managed);
}

public abstract class BaseManager<ManagedType> : IBaseManager<ManagedType>
    where ManagedType : IBaseManaged
{
    protected Dictionary<string, ManagedType> registered = new Dictionary<string, ManagedType>();

    public void Add(ManagedType managed)
    {
        managed.Manager = (IBaseManager<IBaseManaged>)this;
        registered.Add(managed.Name, managed);
    }
    // Other common management tasks
}

public class ConcreteManager : BaseManager<IBaseManaged>
{
    //specialization stuff, e.g.
    public void Refresh() { Console.WriteLine("Refresh() called"); }
}

public interface IBaseManaged
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    IBaseManager<IBaseManaged> Manager { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseManaged : IBaseManaged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IBaseManager<IBaseManaged> Manager { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteManaged : BaseManaged
{
    //specialization stuff, e.g.
    public void Process()
    {
        ((ConcreteManager)Manager).Refresh();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the kind of cyclic relationship you want is not possible to implement perfectly type safe and without casts, because the compiler would end up getting into infinite cycles if you wanted `IBaseManaged` also to be generic (ie, `IBaseManaged<T> where T : IBaseManager<?>`), is clearly not possible to specify the constraint you need in place of `?`.

You can however, create a third interface/class which can fully express this kind of circular constraint, which might provide an alternative solution.

```
interface IManagerAdapter<TManager, TManaged> 
    where TManager : IBaseManager<TManaged>
    where TManaged : IBaseManaged<TManager>
```

IMO, if your `ConcreteManaged` class is going to know directly about `ConcreteManager` by virtue of the type cast anyway, these classes don't really provide much more than a *pattern* to follow for concrete types, the abstraction is kind of broken. If you need this tight coupling between the specific concrete manager and managed types anyway, I would probably make it explicity by adding the specific type in place of `Managed` in each class, and do away with the `BaseManaged` class, which doesn't help very much other than providing the `Name`, which is simple enough to re-implement in concrete instances.

```
public interface IBaseManaged<T> { 
    string Name { get; set; }
    T Manager { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteManaged : IBaseManaged<ConcreteManager> {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ConcreteManager Manager { get; set; }

    public void Process ()
    {
        Manager.Refresh ();
    }
}
```

For anything in the base types which might be more complex to implement than `Name`, I would opt for a Mixin like approach, where you implement that additional functionality in a separate class, and just provide a property in the interface to retreive the Mixin. For example, if all the Manager classes need to account for registering all of the Managed (as with your `Add()`), you obviously don't want to duplicate that functionality in each Manager - but you could simplify the approach by implementing some `ManagedRegister<T>` type, say (can be whatever you like), and giving the `IBaseManager` type a `Registered` field to retreive an instance.

```
public interface IBaseManager<T> {
    ManagedRegister<T> Registered { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteManager : IBaseManager<ConcreteManaged> {
    public ManagedRegister<ConcreteManaged> Registered { get; set; }

    public void Refresh () { Console.WriteLine("Refresh() called"); }
}
```

You still get a strongly typed `Managed` instances from the Register inside the `Manager` here.

The change from your calling code is that instead of `manager.Add(managed)`, it becomes `manager.Registered.Add(managed)`, and you also need to create an instance of `ManagedRegister<ConcreteManaged>` to pass to the `ConcreteManager`.. Perhaps a bit messy, and I would suggest abstracting that away into a factory, which will prevent simple mistakes like forgetting to add managed instances to the manager. We can use that circular constraint from above to implement it in a type safe way. (And if it's possible to assume every Managed/Manager has a parameterless constructor, a single implementation will work by using `new()` constraints. Otherwise you'll want an abstract factory and implement for each concrete type).

```
interface IManagerFactory<TManager, TManaged> 
    where TManager : IBaseManager<TManaged>
    where TManaged : IBaseManaged<TManager> 
{
    TManager Manager { get; }
    TManaged Create (string name);
}

public abstract class ManagerFactory<TManager, TManaged> 
    : IManagerFactory<TManager, TManaged> 
    where TManager : IBaseManager<TManaged>, new()
    where TManaged : IBaseManaged<TManager>, new()
{
    TManager manager = new TManager ();

    public ManagerFactory () {
        manager.Registered = new ManagedRegister<TManaged> ();
    }

    public TManager Manager { get { return manager; } }

    public TManaged Create (string name)
    {
        TManaged result = new TManaged ();
        result.Name = name;
        manager.Registered.Add (result.Name, result);
        result.Manager = manager;
        return result;
    }
}

public class ConcreteFactory 
    : ManagedFactory<ConcreteManager, ConcreteManaged> { }
```

Back to Main, the usage is slightly simplified here.

```
ConcreteFactory f = new ConcreteFactory ();
ConcreteManaged managed = f.CreateManaged ("Test");

managed.Process ();
```

---

EDIT:

Here's abstracting *all* of the common functionality into so called "Base classes". The key difference here is that the Base classes *composed* into the concrete class rather than inherited, by means of the `Base` property, which acts very much like the `base.` prefix you'd use to call base members usually.

```
public class BaseManager<T> {
    public Dictionary<string, T> Registered { get; set; }
}

public interface IBaseManager<T> {
    BaseManager<T> Base { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteManager 
    : IBaseManager<ConcreteManaged> {

    public BaseManager<ConcreteManaged> Base { get; set; }

    public void Refresh() { Console.WriteLine("Refresh() called"); }
}

public class BaseManaged<T> {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Manager { get; set; }
}

public interface IBaseManaged<T> { 
    BaseManaged<T> Base { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteManaged 
    : IBaseManaged<ConcreteManager> {
    public BaseManaged<ConcreteManager> Base { get; set; }

    internal ConcreteManaged () { }

    public void Process () {
        Base.Manager.Refresh ();
    }
}

interface IManagerFactory<TManager, TManaged> 
where TManager : IBaseManager<TManaged>
where TManaged : IBaseManaged<TManager> {
    TManager Manager { get; }
    TManaged Create (string name);
}

public abstract class BaseManagerFactory<TManager, TManaged> 
: IManagerFactory<TManager, TManaged> 
where TManager : IBaseManager<TManaged>, new() 
where TManaged : IBaseManaged<TManager>, new() {
    TManager manager = new TManager();

    public BaseManagerFactory() {
        manager.Base = new BaseManager<TManaged>();
        manager.Base.Registered = new Dictionary<string, TManaged>();
    }

    public TManager Manager { get { return manager; } }

    public TManaged Create (string name) {
        TManaged result = new TManaged();
        result.Base = new BaseManaged<TManager>();
        result.Base.Name = name;
        manager.Base.Registered.Add (name, result);
        result.Base.Manager = manager;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is implementing a pattern that needs to be followed along with a base implementation for the common use. There are different types of concrete managers and managed, I want to make sure that a managed class doesn't inadvertently get added to the wrong type of manager, and I don't want each concrete class to have to implement common functionality (when using the abstract base instead of interface). I think your managed factory approach is a good compromise/start, and I'll probably build from there. Thanks!

Comment: I added a bit more just to clarify what I meant by the Mixin-like base classes. You can still have the base classes to implement common functionality, but the key is to remove inheritance of the `Base*` classes from `Concrete*` ones, and use composition in its place.

Comment: Another point on preventing invalid use of these classes. The Factory is meant to encapsulate all the possible problems that could go wrong, but as it stands there's nothing preventing users from constructing their own concrete types. One possible trick would be to implement `internal` constructors for these classes and have them in the same assembly as the factory - which would ensure the only way to create the instances is through the factory, however, that won't work with the `new()` constraint, so you'd probably need to implement a factory for each concrete type.